# Как удалить сцену при переходе на новую в Corona sdk?

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

Имеется две сцены (*mainMenu* и *gameSpace*) и библиотека Composer. Как при переходе (или после перехода) с *mainMenu* на *gameSpace* удалить *mainMenu*? Переход осуществлен с помощью тапа по изображению на дисплее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предыдущая сцена удалится, если в коде следующей сцены (gameSpace) поместить:

```lua
local composer = require('composer')
composer.removeScene('mainMenu')
```